# No calendar subscriptions showing up on iCloud.com

Tags: data-synchronization, icloud, calendar

I have a number of calendars on the Calendar app on my MacBook Pro (OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2): along with the three standard iCloud calendars (Calendar, Home, Work) I have 7 subscriptions. I have tried a number of things, but it seems none of my calendars except the three standard ones want to appear on iCloud.com. Is this an irreparable bug with the Apple software/servers, or is there something I can do to fix this issue here?

Note: It's odd that the calendars and indeed the list of iCloud subscriptions still seems to sync fine with my iPhone. It's just that none of them display on iCloud.com for whatever reason!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely because iCloud.com only has *iCloud* calendars. Chances are all the rest of your calendars are not iCloud. Honestly, I wouldn't see it as a bug, but something that they haven't added into the online portal. If you click the Settings icon and select Preferences in iCloud.com/#calendar it will not give you an option to add outside calendars.

They will still show up on your phone because it is tied in with your email. If you go to the email account that you are subscribed with, you should see Calendars set to "On".

Comment: I see. But it seems that iCloud syncs my subscriptions anyway, so it's a little odd. I suppose they just haven't bothered adding the ability to view subscriptions to the iCloud.com site. It's slightly disconcerting when such things are apparently missing, in any case.

Comment: It also brings me to a slightly more pertinent question: how can I rearrange iCloud calendars then? I saw some tip online that says you can rearrange them via iCloud.com... since in the Calendar app on OS X, the ordering of subscriptions simply resets to some arbitrary order as soon as it syncs again!

Comment: @Noldorin, I'd guess that iCloud doesn't actually store the subscribed calendar's data. It may sync the settings to other devices, however. Rearranging the calendars - you can't see the subscribed calendars in iCloud so it wouldn't work to re-arrange it there, right?

Comment: Indeed, that seems to be the case unfortunately.

Comment: If no other suggestions come along, I'll accept your answer, since at least it confirms the negative case.

Comment: Makes sense - thanks. I usually like to provide workarounds, but honestly, I just couldn't find *any* way to do that. It would be nice if someone else knew a way.

Comment: Indeed. Apple routinely seem averse to enabling rearranging/reordering of lists in certain places. Don't know why. If it at least sorted alphabetically it would be okay..

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for this I have found, but essentially requires you to setup a local iCloud calendar then share it to another calendar provider online and then on that calendar subscribe to the ical

Comment: This is still driving me nuts now that sunrise is dead, there appears to be no reasonable solution and no rational reason for icloud.com not supporting subscribed calendars which are vital to everyday life.